About ARMv8-A `SVC #0x0f0f` to machine code
Below is objdump -D output:
80730:  d401e1e1    svc #0x0f0f

First column is the address and second is machine code, final is instruction.
I know the SVC opcode code is 0xd4, but why 0x0f0f become to 0x1e1e1 ?
I want to know how 0x0f0f transfers to 0x1e1e1.
Thanks for any reply.

According to Section C4.1.93.2, Exception Generation, in the Arm Architecture Reference Manual for A-profile architecture, the 0x0f0f is shifted over 5 bits. The fields in the SVC instruction are:

opc, op2 and LL for SVC are

So hex((0b000 << 20) | (0x0f0f << 5) | 0b00001) is 0x1e1e1.

Please check if you can turn these pictures into text for better accessibility.  You could e.g. use a table.

I added a python snippet to make it more clear.
